Continuous Beam Deflections from Moment Diagram Non Prismatic
I am building a spreadsheet for a continuous beam upto 4 spans and cantilevers (each span having three segments of different EI). I have done reactions via slope deflection method and then built shear diagram. For moment diagram I have used just numerical integration of shear diagram. I now want to find deflection at each of the points which i used for building shear and bending.
What I understand is i can use conjugate beam or moment area method for which i will require to get reactions of M/EI diagram and it will be quite of a work for irregular shaped bending moment diagram. Is there any simple way i can achieve it numerically if any of you have can think of simpler solution?

If you know M/EI at each short segment you know the radius of curvature, so you can find the deflection of that segment. To be honest you've done the hardest bit if you have worked out the reaction forces at each support.
